# node js express cannot post - getting Cannot POST error message

Tags: node.js, json, rest, express, postman

I am new in nodeJS, I have created this application:

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();

app.use (express.json());
app.post('api/hostels', (req, res) => {
    const hostel = {
        id : hostels.length + 1,
        name: req.body.name
    };
    hostels.push(hostel);
    res.send(hostel);
});
```

I send this body in the PostMan raw body (json)

```
{
    "id": "4",
    "name" : "new Request"
}
```

but I am getting this error:

```
 <body>
        <pre>Cannot POST /api/requests</pre>
    </body>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, you did a small mistake while defining a route of the express. 
you have `app.post('api/hostels', (req, res) => {})` instead you should have `app.post('/api/hostels', (req, res) => {})`

Answer (score 0):

You are posting to `/api/requests`, your endpoint shows `/api/hostels`. Change the endpoint on your postman to `/api/hostels`.

Answer (score 0):

There is a mistake in your post, theres a missing `/` in you app.post

it should be `app.post('/api/hostels', (req, res) => { }`